# Grouping in R by timestamp

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a data frame with the following columns:

```
Timestamp - POSIXct
Number of users - integer
number of schools - integer
country code - factor
```

[image: Screenshot]

What I would like to do is to create a new column for the whole data frame grouping the sum of the number of users by timestamp  as well as by country code. So for example for timestamp A (2019-03-01) the total number of users is for country x is ... and for country y is ... .

I have tried to use the `dplyr` package, especially the mutate function, but somehow could this not get to work.

I have tried to use `ggplot` and the `stat_summary` argument, but somehow `ggplot` shows me not the total sum, but the number of users per country per timestamp.

A sample dput output is the following:

```
structure(list(date_intervall = structure(c(1559340000, 1559340000, 
1559340000, 1559340000, 1561932000, 1561932000, 1561932000, 1561932000, 
1561932000, 1561932000, 1561932000, 1564610400, 1564610400, 1564610400, 
1564610400, 1564610400, 1564610400, 1564610400, 1567288800, 1567288800, 
1567288800, 1567288800, 1567288800, 1567288800, 1567288800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), number_of_students = c(28470L, 28L, 54L, 
754L, 1376L, 2299L, 2632L, 28470L, 28L, 68L, 1003L, 1380L, 2299L, 
3584L, 28470L, 28L, 69L, 1003L, 1384L, 2350L, 5078L, 28470L, 
28L, 72L, 1003L), number_of_schools = c(66L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 
4L, 10L, 66L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 15L, 66L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 
22L, 66L, 1L, 3L, 1L), country_code = structure(c(3L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("AU", "ID", "PL", "SG", "VN"
), class = "factor")), row.names = 86:110, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: If all you want is totals by 2 columns why use a graphics package like `ggplot2`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not solve the issue using the answer provided in the original question. I do not want to get a new df, I just want to keep the original one with an additional column.

Comment: I have used ggplot for visualization purposes. The code is the following pl <- ggplot(data=d, aes(x=date_intervall,y=number_of_students,fill=country_code)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum,geom = 'bar'). But it does not stack the bars to show the total number, but only arrange them one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still fail to understand the question but try the following.

First, load the required packages.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

Now, if you want a new column in the original data set, use `mutate`, not `summarise` and assign the result back to `d`.

```
d <- d %>%
  group_by(date_intervall, country_code) %>%
  mutate(total_students = sum(number_of_students))
```

To plot the totals, use `summarise` and pipe to `ggplot`. Note that I plot with `geom_col`, not `geom_bar`.

```
d %>%
  group_by(date_intervall, country_code) %>%
  summarise(total_students = sum(number_of_students)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date_intervall, y = total_students, fill = country_code)) + 
  geom_col()
```

Comment: Thank you, Rui ! I did not group the data accordingly, more specifically did not group  it by country_code.